# Replacing items using a foreach loop in a 2D array with userinput

Tags: c#

I have a 2D array with 9 strings:

```
public static string[,] theGrid = new string[,] 
{
    { "1", "2", "3" },
    { "4", "5", "6"},
    { "7", "8", "9" }
};
```

Here's my draw method, formatted funky to look like a TicTacToe grid:

```
public static void drawGrid()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("- - - - - - - - -\n| {0}  |  {1}  |  {2}  " +
"|\n| \n| {3}  |  {4}  |  {5}  |\n|\n| {6}  |  {7}  " +
"|  {8}  |\n- - - - - - - - -"
, theGrid[0, 0], theGrid[0, 1], theGrid[0, 2], theGrid[1, 0],
theGrid[1, 1], theGrid[1, 2], theGrid[2, 0], theGrid[2, 1], theGrid[2, 2]);

    }
```

I'm trying to loop through each position in the using this method:

```
    public static void getInput()
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (Player.player1)
        {
            foreach (string s in theGrid)
            {
                if (input == s)
                {
                    s = Console.WriteLine("X");

                    break;
                }
```

I'm getting the exception: "Cannot assign to 's' because it is a 'foreach itteration variable'. I'm basically trying to get the user to enter the position of the string on the grid. The program should loop through each string to see if it matches the user input, if it does, I want the number to be replaced by an 'X'.

Comment: You cannot modify a collection in a `foreach` loop. Try a `for` loop instead. Also `Console.WriteLine` has a `void` return type and assigning `s` something that never returns anything makes no sense.

Comment: You should use `Equals` instead...

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen didn't realize I couldn't modify a foreach loop, thanks! Could you clarify the second part? Are you talking about my getInput() method being void?

Comment: @Hackerman you're right, thank you.

Comment: Glad to help @Kiddo

Comment: Check the return type of Console.Writeline().its Void .

Comment: @DebashishSaha gotcha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't do any input validation, which I think you probably should.  I also made it flexible so you could do more then a 3 X 3 grid so long as it stay's a 2 dimensional array of string. If you don't need/want that you can remove the .GetLength calls and replace them with 3 because its a 3 by 3 grid.  I'm also assuming you only have two players, an x and o.

```
public static void getInput()
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string mark = Player.player1 ? "X" : "O";
        for (int x = 0; x < theGrid.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < theGrid.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                if (!input.Equals(theGrid[x, y])) continue;
                theGrid[x, y] = mark;
                // Assuming your done with this method, so just returning because we don't need to search the rest of the grid
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works beautifully, thank you for putting the extra effort in with the Mark variable. Clever and really helped.

Answer (score 1):

To modify array element you need to write something like this:

```
public static void getInput()
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (Player.player1)
        {
                for (var row = 0; row < theGrid.GetLength(0); row++)
                {
                    for (var column = 0; column < theGrid.GetLength(1); column++)
                    {
                        if (input == theGrid[row, column])
                        {
                            theGrid[row, column] = "X";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
       ...
```

Comment: appreciate the response!